# Nested Query not executing as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Catalog(ID, CourseName, PreReq, Professor)  
PreviousCourses(Username, PreviousCoursesID, Grade)
```

`PreviousCoursesID` corresponds to `ID` in Catalog. I am trying to access the CourseName using this relation.

Here is my query:

```
Select CourseName from Catalog where ID = (Select PrevCoursesID from PreviousCourses where Username = 'admin')
```

It executes but returns an empty set.

The `Select PrevCoursesID from PreviousCourses where Username = 'admin'` query by itself returns the `PrevCoursesID` so I do not understand why my nested query is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select CourseName from Catalog where ID = (Select PrevCoursesID from PreviousCourses where Username = 'admin')
```

Needs to use the "IN" instead of "=" like this

```
Select CourseName from Catalog where ID IN (Select PrevCoursesID from PreviousCourses where Username = 'admin')
```

Because it is a set of values rather than a single value. when checking for more than 1 value, you need to use the IN keyword. this would be the same as

```
Select CourseName from Catalog where ID = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: What does **Select PrevCoursesID from PreviousCourses where Username = 'admin'** return?

Comment: 10000. It returns the PrevCoursesID data where the username is admin

Comment: is that the value 1000 or 1000 results? if it is the value 1000 then try **Select CourseName from Catalog where ID = 1000**

Comment: Never mind. I found the error. The two values from the two columns didn't match. I accidentally added an extra 0 in one of the columns...